# What is Internet Explorer development?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm trying to understand what Internet Explorer development is.

If web sites are run in Internet Explorer, then why do we need Internet Explorer development.  Why not just use web development?

Puzzled.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Where did you find this term? I know that some corporate web applications will only run in IE (not in other browsers) because of compatibility. Perhaps that's what was meant?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure of what you mean by "Where did you find this term?".  What term?

Comment: I meant where did you read about 'Internet Explorer development'; in which context was it used?

Comment: When I go to the MSDN Developer Center: https://msdn.microsoft.com/developer-centers-msdn.  It seems like there is a special section to develop for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Also, the MSDN forums have a forum for Internet Explorer development: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=iewebdevelopment&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc

Comment: OK, that is just web development (as you suspected) with a small IE flavor. IE handles some things differently than other browsers do.